# Java constructor reflection throws exception with sealed classes

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

I have the following sealed class in a Kotlin project:

```
sealed class Test {

    abstract val test: String

    @NoArg
    data class Test1(
            override val test: String
    ) : Test()

    @NoArg
    data class Test2(
            override val test: String
    ) : Test()
}
```

The `@NoArg` annotation is a marker and the compiler is configured to generate a no argument constructor for these classes.

My problem is that trying to instantiate `Test1` and `Test2` using Java reflection results in the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:27)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method Test.<init>()V from class Test$Test1
    at Test$Test1.<init>(Main.kt)
    ... 5 more
```

I initially encountered this problem when trying to load instances of these classes from a Mongo database using Spring Data Mongo.

The code I used to instantiate them during this test is the following:

```
val javaConstructor = Test.Test1::class.java.getConstructor()
        ?: error("Did not find constructor")

val instance = javaConstructor.newInstance()
```

My current workaround is to just not use a sealed class which solves the Exception. Is there a way I can keep the sealed class and make Java reflection work correctly? I don't think this is quite the intended behaviour, but maybe there is some sort of reason to this? If so, I'd be interested to hear what it is.

I have an example of my problem here: https://github.com/mhlz/playground

Comment: Have you tried `isAccessible = true`?

Comment: Yes, in my example project I have set accesible true on the constructor it complains about in the exception. It does not help.

Comment: I can't say what will do `@NoArg` annotation because it depends on your compoler configuration. But if you specify default values for all constructor parameters, e. g. `data class Test1(override val test: String = "") ...`, compiler will generate no-arg constructor.

Comment: The annotation does exactly that by using the official [no-arg compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin)

Comment: This might be best to report as an issue to Youtrack for Kotlin